# Difference between ACTIVE and NORMAL state

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been using Tkinter from couple of weeks. One thing I have noticed is that the tkinter widgets (Button, etc.) have 3 states: `NORMAL`, `ACTIVE` and `DISABLED`. I understand the `NORMAL` and `DISABLED` states. Whats the difference between the `ACTIVE` and `NORMAL` states?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tk sets state = ACTIVE when a mouse is over a non-DISABLED button option (i.e. NORMAL) It can then be made to appear raised, sunken, flat, flash etc. So basically, NORMAL enables a button while ACTIVE
can change the appearance settings on mouse over etc. Hope this helps, there's a great post about it here:

http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/Widgets/Button