# Tkinter checkbox with command attached

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I would like some help with something simple: A tkinter checkbox that *does have a command attached* <--this simple example is *always* mentioned but never shown in tutorials on the web.

I have:

```
from tkinter import *

def activateMotors(active):
    scale.config(state=active)


root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Servo Control')
motorsOn= IntVar()
motorsCheck=Checkbutton(root,text="Motors ON(checked)/OFF(unchecked)", variable=motorsOn, command=activateMotors)
motorsCheck.pack()
scale = Scale(root, from_=0, to=180, 
              orient=HORIZONTAL,label="Motor #",state=DISABLED)
scale.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This does not work. Sure the window comes up but when I click on the checkbox I get "TypeError activateMotors() missing 1 required positional argument 'active' "

Can anybody correct this so that we can have one operational checkbox example with commands?

Comment: Have you tried removing the argument?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The callback must not have arguments, we must use the `get()` function of `IntVar`

```
from tkinter import *

def activateMotors():
    if motorsOn.get() == 1:
        scale.config(state=ACTIVE)
    elif motorsOn.get() == 0:
        scale.config(state=DISABLED)


root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Servo Control')
motorsOn= IntVar()
motorsCheck=Checkbutton(root, 
    text="Motors ON(checked)/OFF(unchecked)", 
    variable=motorsOn, 
    command=activateMotors)
motorsCheck.pack()

scale = Scale(root, from_=0, to=180, 
              orient=HORIZONTAL,label="Motor #",state=DISABLED)
scale.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, it seems so. some minutes later I found that similar to yours, except that I did not use ACTIVE but NORMAL. I suppose they are synonymous

Comment: @KansaiRobot according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125671), "NORMAL enables a button while ACTIVE can change the appearance settings on mouse over etc."